# Задача по теоритической информатике

Tags: информатика

Условие

> Имеется поле размера w * h (1 ≤ w, h ≤ 40000), на котором расставлены N ладей (0 ≤ N ≤ min(w, h)).
>
> Каждая ладья задаётся координатой (x, y) (1≤ x ≤ w, 1 ≤ y ≤ h) на поле и бьёт все клетки, находящиеся с ней на одной горизонтали или вертикали. Опишите эффективный алгоритм нахождения максимального по площади прямоугольника, клетки которого не бьёт ни одна из ладей.

Свои идеи: я думал, но чего-то логически правильного у меня не получилось пока

Comment: 1 - пишите ваши идеи. 2 - сложность правильного ответа будет O(N log N).

Comment: Могут ли фигуры бить друг друга (т.е. пересекаются ли поля разных ладей)?

Comment: не знаю, но думаю, что да

Comment: У меня получилось два решения: 1) O(N * log(N)) по вычислениям и O(N) по памяти; 2) O(max(w, h)) по вычислениям и O(max(w, h)) по памяти.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача стоит в том, чтобы найти самы большой по площади прямоугольник. В 2 двумерныx массивa будем записывать координаты верхнего левого и нижнего правого угла каждого квадрата, не под боем. Начинаем с a[1,1] и b[w,h]. По одной добавляем ладью на поле и переписываем квадраты. Допустим, поле 6х6, ладья стоит на x=3,y=3. Тогда в массиы идут A[1,1][1+x,1][1+x,1][1+x,1+x] B[x-1,y-1][w,y-1][x-1,h][w,h]
Так, добавим все ладьи и затем найдем самый большой прямоугольник из 2х пар координат. Естественно из массива нужно будет удалять координаты предыдущих итераций, и удалять координаты, у которых длина площадь равно 0.

Не уверен что это очень эффективно, но по требованиям памяти и скорость для олимпиадных задач должен влезть. Или хотя бы дать почву для размышлений)